# Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.0.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5/../lib/tools.jar

Tags: spring-boot, maven, evosuite

I'm trying to use evosuit maven plugin(1.0.6) to generate unit tests for my spring boot application. I have followed the official documentation at https://www.evosuite.org/documentation/maven-plugin/. Searching on the web I went to discover that tools.jar has been removed from JDK 9.

So question is: how can I do without this jar file? Downgrade to java 8 is not an option.

I also tried latest version of the evosuite plugin (1.2.0), but I receive this errors:
**Unresolved dependency: 'org.evosuite:evosuite-standalone-runtime:jar:1.2.0'
Unresolved plugin: 'org.evosuite.plugins:evosuite-maven-plugin:1.2.0'**

This is part of my pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
        <leda-be-framework-version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</leda-be-framework-version>
        <mapstruct-version>1.5.3.Final</mapstruct-version>
        <lombok-mapstruct-binding-version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding-version>
        <lombok-version>1.18.24</lombok-version>
        <evosuiteVersion>1.0.6</evosuiteVersion>
        <surefire-mvn-plugin-version>3.1.0</surefire-mvn-plugin-version>
 </properties>
...
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.evosuite</groupId>
            <artifactId>evosuite-standalone-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${evosuiteVersion}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.evosuite.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>evosuite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${evosuiteVersion}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This is the maven command i use to generate unit tests:
mvn evosuite:generate evosuite:export

Thanks in advance for your help!